# Find a value of $K>0$ such that the implication is true..$|x+4|\leq 2$ implies that $|{(x+1 )^2 /(x+7)}−3|>K|x+4|$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

My final result comes to be $-11/5> k$, which can’t be as $k>0$. Would appreciate assistance.[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

$$|x+4|\leq2 \implies -6\leq x\leq 2\\
|\frac{(x+1)^2}{x+7}-3|=|\frac{x^2-x-20}{x+7}|=|\frac{(x+4)(x-5)}{x+7}|=f(x)$$ if you find range of $f(x)$ on interval $-6\leq x\leq 2$ you will find $f(x) \in [0,22]$ then you must solve it for $$|\frac{(x+4)(x-5)}{x+7}|>k|x+4|\\
\frac{|x+4||x-5|}{|x+7|}>k|x+4|\\
|x-5|>k|x+7|$$ can you take over ?
you can came across with
$$\frac{|x+4||x-5|}{|x+7||x+4|}>k\\ when \\ -6\leq x\leq 2$$ when $x \neq -4$
so
$$k<\frac{|x-5|}{|x+7|},k\neq 0\\k<|\frac{x-5}{x+7}|$$

Comment: my k still comes the same . U can see my working attached above .

Comment: @TasniaTanjid:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j7o3cd4zyf

Comment: @TasniaTanjid: I prefer to draw both sides as a function then decide because the problem is somehow hard.

Comment: @TasniaTanjid: at the last line of your writing , |(x-5)/(x+7)| is between two minus number  ?? how its possible?